# Assigning character to 2D array in c language

Tags: arrays, integer, 2d, character, assign

I am keep tryin to assigning char '-' to every element of a 2D array. Arrays size is unknown but now i'm just trying 10x10. I tried something like that:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(j=0; j<10; j++){
        tableArray[i][j] = {'-', '-'};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    for(j=0; j<10; j++){
        tableArray[i][j] = '-';
    }
}
```